# Can a desktop PWA be set as "always on top" of other applications?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, desktop

I have developed a counter in Vuejs with PWA and **I want to keep it always on top** for desktop, is this possible?. 
I have been doing some research and found nothing yet.

Thanks.

FYI: It is a productivity method based on the technique of Pomodoro but with timers of 55' instead of 25'. If you want to know more about it I have written a post in [medium](https://medium.com/@ctwux/diamond-productivity-method-achieve-and-master-your-productivitys-routine-dream-fa692b79040b).

[image: Diamond Productivity method, https://diamond-app.com]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some digging, a workaround I came with was to enable a custom `<Picture in Picture>` canvas created by hand, see example here:
https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/qBEwrbJ

Comment: Cool you found a solution

Comment: No exact solution but a workaround to display certain data into <picture in picture> windows that I create dynamically, take a look at the codepen. I didn't find how to keep the whole application on top of others yet. I don' think it is possible.

Comment: That was also my original answer (pity it lost 1 upvote since yesterday)...AFAIK there is not an "out of the box solution"

Comment: Drawing on a canvas element is nothing to do with PWA or related to the "always on top" issue.  Please can you explain in your answer how this is a workaround?

Comment: The only way I found to have an always-on-top window with only HTML is to draw on a canvas and set the picture in a picture. I wish that PWA would support the option at some point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to use third party scripts to achieve this. Your PWA  application will run within a browser (eg. Chrome) and the "always on top" setting is not something you can achieve from your application.

There are some tools for [Windows](https://www.techjunkie.com/always-on-top-windows-10/) and [Mac](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mac-keeping-your-application-window-always-on-top/) though that would allow what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, the workaround is very nice, but what I want is to include it into the PWA, so the future users don't have to use third-party applications.

Comment: I do not think this is possible just via PWA. You need to change the default behaviour of windows priority on a local level, therefore you would need to run some kind of script on the user's side to achieve this.

Comment: thanks, maybe in the future there will be more options to involve the local operative system with PWA, as we have now with hardware access like Bluetooth and others.