# Keep browser window always on top for a valid use case

Tags: javascript, html, angular, browser

I'm looking for a reliable way to get a browser window always on top. I know some old methods like window.focus(), blur events and so on but they don't work anymore.

I was wondering if there is some kind of way to get the user trust to keep a specific browser window always on top on the desktop.

The use case is simple. I'm letting the user to capture and record their screen and I want to let them record their face as well. For that, I'm opening a popup (window.open) and enabling their webcam. This window must be always on top in order to get their face always visible when the user is managing other windows.

Is this achievable? Thanks!

Comment: I think you would need a native application to have such permissions. I would be extremely pissed off if a browser allowed a window to just stay on top all the time

Comment: @JuanMendes hence the mentioned "get user trust" requirement.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you'd need to create a native app for that level of permission. Instead, you could show your users how to keep it on top themselves, as there are a bunch of platform specific ways of doing this

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I'm saying that it's not common to trust webapps that much and it could be abused. Rubén, this is a similar answer that also says you'd need a native app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58167191/227299

Comment: Thanks everyone. Everything’s clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking for exists, no.

The closest that I can think of is the [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), but that won't work for your use case — it sounds like you want other windows to be visible, just not on top.

I think you'll have to use user training to get the best results you can, telling them to be sure that their face is visible and not behind some other window.